# Should async method calls chain up in all method calls scope?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.1

I am writing a asp.net core web API which is consuming another third party API and returning some JSON response back to the caller which will be a client web browser. While writing my implementation in asynchronous manner the visual studio is suggesting to remove async await from my following async methods.

I just wanted to get clarification that i don't need to wrap these two method in async await ?

Following are the methods:

```
public async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string url)
{
    return  await GetResponse<T>(HttpMethod.GET,url);
}

public async Task<T> PostAsync<T>(string url, object payload)
{
    return await GetResponse<T>(HttpMethod.POST, url,payload);       
}
```

and following is method that is consumed by the above two methods :

```
public async Task<T> GetResponse<T>(HttpMethod method,string url, object payload = null)
{
    System.Net.Http.HttpClient client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response;

    switch (method)
    {
        case HttpMethod.POST:
        {
            var content = new StringContent(payload.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            response = await client.PostAsync(url, content).ConfigureAwait(false);
            break;
        }
        case HttpMethod.GET:
        default:
            method = HttpMethod.GET;
            response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            break;
    }


   var responseMessageString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

   _logger.LogInformation($"{method.ToString()} {method.ToString()} {Environment.NewLine} Response: {responseMessageString}");

    return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseMessageString);
}
```

Following is the suggestion from Visual Studio :

[image]

Async in method declaration and await may be elided

Comment: At one point they were thinking of having the compiler [automatically remove these](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1981). For a few reasons relating to exception handling, it wasn't done. If you've not even thought about exceptions here though, no reason you shouldn't.

Comment: The pros and cons of [eliding async / await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever let's say we do want exception handling, then?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad You don't need to wrap them. Since those methods (`GetAsync`, `PostAsync`) are just pass-through and there are no other methods called within them, you can remove the async-await and just return the task

Comment: @Nkosi thanks for your input, so the caller of  `GetAsync` and `PostAsync` should have `async` and `await` as it have other lines of code that should be executed after the get and post call returns the response

Comment: @EhsanSajjad that is correct. You should review the article linked by  Johnathan Barclay above

Comment: @Nkosi i will read for sure, i may be off topic regarding this question, but i can also see resharper suggesting to handle `ConfigureAwait` for the calls, can you shed some light on that part if you don't mind

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I always defer to this Reference *[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2013/march/async-await-best-practices-in-asynchronous-programming)* with regrds to that topic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I just wanted to get clarification that i don't need to wrap these two method in async await?

That is correct. You can trust the recommendations made by Visual Studio and ReSharper; they are very conservative in their recommendations.

In this case, because each method just passes arguments to another method and returns the same thing, it is safe to [elide the `async` and `await`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html).

However, I wouldn't feel that you *have* to. Eliding the keywords gives you a (very) minor increase in performance. But if those methods do anything non-trivial - or *are changed in the future to do anything non-trivial* - then you would want to keep the `async`/`await` keywords.

Comment: Thanks @Stephen but what you would suggest about the recommendation to ConfigureAwait, is it required in .NET core based apis  still ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad: I still recommend `ConfigureAwait(false)` for general-purpose libraries. If you're on ASP.NET Core, then [you don't need to use it](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2017/03/aspnetcore-synchronization-context.html).